# How to do pagination in c# mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

How to do pagination in C# MVC?

I'm trying to do something like this,

I want retrieve 1000 records from database and keep it in server side then i want to send 10 records per each page to view when user requesting the searched page.

I have gone through some examples but i couldn't get better solution, I prefer that the way i suggested or something better solution for this. (I'm using jquery as well and not using Razor)

example which I gone through

[Paginated search results with LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793718/paginated-search-results-with-linq-to-sql)

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a package from Microsoft called WebMatrix that has a WebGrid in it that supports paging, you could give that a try.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Paging in ASP.NET MVC is a solved problem by some libraries; you can find them at Nuget.org by
http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=paging.

> I want retrieve 1000 records from database and keep it in server side then i want to send 10 records per each page to view when user requesting the searched page.

Retrieving 1000 records and keep them in your application wouldn't be ideal. It would be better to retrieve 10 records in every request; as you have mentioned in your question, the solution that use `Skip` and `Take` in a linq query is perfect. However, there is no problem to page cached data.

Answer (score 0):

Try This
One of the easiest method

Controller

```
using PagedList;
public ActionResult Index(int ? pagePos)
{
        //return View(db.Items.ToList());// Change this as following
        int pageNumber = (pagePos ?? 1);
        return View(db.Items.ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, 30)); //30 is the size of records in a single page
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@*@model IEnumerable<ProjectDB.Models.Item>*@
@*Change These Also as following*@
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ProjectDB.Models.Item>
@using PagedList.Mvc


<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>
        ID
    </th>

    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}   
</table>

@*Pagination Code Starts*@

<div class="pageCount">
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
</div>
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, pagePos => Url.Action("Index", new { pagePos }))
```

Answer (score -1):

```cs
 public class PaginationVM<T> where T : IEnumerable

 public async Task<IActionResult> ProductPagination(int page = 1, int count = 8)
 {
     var items = _db.Product.Skip((page - 1) * count).Take(count).Select(s => new ProductListItemVM
     {

         Id = s.Id,
         Name = s.Name,
         ProductCode = s.ProductCode,
         About = s.About,
         Description = s.Description,
         SellPrice = s.SellPrice,
         CostPrice = s.CostPrice,
         Discount = s.Discount,
         Quantity = s.Quantity,
         CategoryId = s.CategoryId,
         ProductMainImg = s.ProductMainImg,
         IsDeleted = s.IsDeleted,
         TagId = s.TagProducts.Select(a => a.TagId).ToList(),

     });
     int totalCount = await _db.Product.CountAsync();
     PaginationVM<IEnumerable<ProductListItemVM>> pag = new(totalCount, page, (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalCount / count), items);

     return PartialView("_ProductPaginationPartial", pag);
 }

 @section Scripts{
     <script>

         $("#dataTable").on("click", "#prod-pag a", function (ev) {
             ev.preventDefault();
             fetch($(this).attr("href"))
                 .then(res => res.text())
                 .then(data => $("#dataTable").html(data))
         })
     </script>
 }
      
          <partial model="Model" name="_ProductPaginationPartial" />


                    <td>@string.Join(",",item.Tag.Select(x=>x.Title))</td>

    <ul id="prod-pag" class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item  @(Model.HasPrev ? "" : "disabled")"><a class='page-link' asp-action="ProductPagination" asp-route-page="@(Model.CurrentPage - 1)" asp-route-count="4">Previous</a></li>
        @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.LastPage; i++)
        {
            <li class="page-item @(i == Model.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")"><a class="page-link" asp-action="ProductPagination" asp-route-page="@i" asp-route-count="4">@i</a></li>
        }
        <li class="page-item @(Model.HasNext ? "" : "disabled")"><a class="page-link" asp-action="ProductPagination" asp-route-page="@(Model.CurrentPage + 1)" asp-route-count="4">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**